# Storing small data .json

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

I want to add a kind of currency to my bot which will tell who contributed the most. I tried setting up a .json file with some youtube tutorial, but that didn't really work. I would like it to look +/- like this ([photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnAkl.png)). As you can see you have the user on the left and then the money they donated, the command used to add would be @addval [user] [amount], @delval [user] [amount] to remove and @top to see the top10. 
Here is the code if anybody would like to add onto this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
var lastbuffer;
lastbuffer = 0;
const client = new Discord.Client();
const BufferClear = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#1DFF98')
.setTitle('**Buffers are clear!**')
.setDescription ('♥️ Buffers are CLEAR! ♥️')
.addField("Checked by: ", "Somebody", true)
.setTimestamp()
.setFooter('Buffers clear. Now go grind!')
const BufferNClear = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setColor('#FF0000')
.setTitle('Buffers are NOT clear!')
.setDescription('Enemies are building a cannon on us!')
.addField("Triggered By: ", 'user.id', true)
.addField("Time triggered: " + 'rdg', true)
.setTimestamp()
.setFooter('we got splitL')



client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');


});
            client.on('message', message => {
                if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}start`)){
                    message.delete()
                    setInterval(function(){
                    lastbuffer++;
                    const Buffer = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor('#8300FF')
                    .setTitle("**It's time to check buffers!**")
                    .setDescription("**It's been **" + "`" + lastbuffer + " Hour" + "`" + "** since last buffercheck, <@&700343773342990337>**." + " **Check now!**")
                    .setThumbnail('https://art.pixilart.com/88534e2f28b65a4.png')
                    .setFooter('WEEEEEWOOOOO')
                    .setTimestamp();
                        client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send(Buffer).then(msg => {
                            msg.react('✅');
                            msg.react('');
                            msg.delete({timeout: 9000})
                        });
                    }, 10000)
                }
                    message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id != message.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '✅' || reaction.emoji.name == ''),
                        { max: 1, time: 2147483647 }).then(collected => {


                         if (collected.first().emoji.name == '✅') {
                            message.delete()
                            client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send(BufferClear);
                            lastbuffer = 0;
                         } else {
                            message.delete()
                            client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send("<@&675688526460878848> Stay alert! Enemies on our walls!")
                            client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send("<@&675688526460878848> Stay alert! Enemies on our walls!")
                            client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send("<@&675688526460878848> Stay alert! Enemies on our walls!")
                            client.channels.cache.get("700489735352746045").send(BufferNClear)
                            lastbuffer = 0;   
                         } 
                        }
                        ).catch(() => {
            })
        })
 client.login(token);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Interesting, this doesn't look like java.

Comment: my bad, did a mistake

Comment: No worries man, edited it :p

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Node.js' [`File System`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to store userIDs and their balance.